# fetch 200k records in single jpa select query within 5 seconds

Tags: performance, hibernate, jpa

I want to fetch 200k records in single jpa select query within 5 seconds. I am selecting one column which is already indexed. Currently It is taking more than 5 minutes. is it possible to select over 100k of records in 5 seconds?

Comment: Try to use raw query using jdbc instead of hibernate.

Comment: I tried using native query still it is very slow

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with hibernate or normal native query since it has to create hundreds of thousands of objects in java side and results needs to be sent over the network (Serialization & de-serialization). 
You could do below steps for fine tuning,

1. At DB side you could change the index method default is binery tree instead set it as "HASH" method.
2. Use Parallel threads to retrieve the results in paginated mode (Use native SQL).

Hope it gives some inputs for further fine tuning.

Answer (score 0):

Use this property to retrieve lakh of records.

```
query.setHint(org.hibernate.fetchSize, 5000);
```